# Why Can't set Method in Seaborn's displot Rotate Tick Labels, While set_xticklabels Works?

Tags: python, seaborn

I'm working with Seaborn's displot for creating histograms and facing an issue with rotating x-tick labels. While I can successfully rotate the labels using g.set_xticklabels(rotation=45), I encounter problems when trying to achieve this through the g.set() method. Here's a comparison of what works and what doesn't:

Works:

```
import seaborn as sns
# Example data and plot creation
g = sns.displot(data=my_data, x='my_column')
# Rotating labels successfully
g.set_xticklabels(rotation=45)
```

Doesn't Work:

```
# Trying to rotate labels using set method
g.set(xticklabels=[rotation=45])
```

Could someone explain why g.set(xticklabels=[rotation=45]) can't rotate the tick labels, and if there's a way to use the set method for this purpose?

Comment: Well, `g.set(xticklabels=[rotation=45])` isn't how `g.set(....)` works. Why do you think `g.set_xticklabels(rotation=45)` is a problem?

Comment: I do not think g.set_xticklabels(rotation=45) is a problem actually. I just think that g.set(...) should do the same thing as it is a unified method to do customization.

Answer (score 0):

i am using something like that for rotating

axs[0].set_xticklabels(axs[0].get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, fontsize=14)

I think you need to change axs[0] with g.

Comment: Yes, I did use g.set_xticklabels and it worked. I'm just curious why g.set() can't achieve that.